# How does one replace WooCommerce default placeholder image for shop categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried the following code, which im using successfully with product thumbnails but for categories haven't found a way to do it.

```
add_action( 'init', 'mw_replace_woocommerce_placeholders' );

function mw_replace_woocommerce_placeholders() {

    add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img', 'custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img');

    function custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img( $src ) {
        $src = '<span class="thumb-placeholder"><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>';
        return $src;
    }

}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_placeholder' );
function custom_placeholder() {
if ( is_product_category() ){
add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src','custom_placeholder_img');

    function custom_placeholder_img($src) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploads = untrailingslashit( $upload_dir['baseurl'] );
    $src = $uploads . '/your/directory/custom_placeholder.jpg';
    return $src;
    }
  }
 }
```

Or you could replace the placeholder located at "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png" with your own.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My first attempt was by using that filter, bud that expects an image url while I was looking to do the same as above, that is replace the image altogether with a different html structure.

Comment: You could make a theme's hack, too, but that depends on your theme.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
if ( is_product_category() ){
```

in functions.php makes the theme reliant on the plugin, so if you deactivate woocommerce for testing, it breaks the site. At least that's what happened to me.